# Rails 3 username password in URL for authenticated Devise resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm confused on why I can't get this to work in the browser. I want to test an authenticated Devise resource using a URL with the username and password in the URL as such

```
http://joe:1234@localhost:3000/blog/latest
```

It doesn't authenticate and instead redirects me to Devise login page. If however, I make it a json call, it works

```
http://joe:1234@localhost:3000/blog/latest.json
```

It also works if I test it using `curl`

```
curl http://joe:1234@localhost:3000/blog/latest
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Devise uses navigational formats to determine if it should issue a 401 when authenticating. JSON and XML requests will 401 by default. HTML request, however, will redirect to the login. To fix this, go to devise.rb in your initializers, uncomment this line and remove HTML from the array:

```
config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*"]
```

Answer (score 0):

May want to look into token authenticable from devise.  This is probably the most effective way to pass credentials right out of the box with devise.

Token Authenticatable: signs in a user based on an authentication token (also known as “single access token”). The token can be given both through query string or HTTP Basic Authentication.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/

Going more in depth, and if you need a reusable strategy as this post suggest, here is a How-To: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-HTTP-Authentication

Devise does have built in HTTP Basic Authentication yet you do need to have two little things in your app to have it working :

```
* :database_authenticatable strategy in your user/account model
* config.http_authenticatable = true in the devise initializer
```

Comment: I already have both Devise settings, `:database_authenticatable` and `config.http_authenticatable` but if you look at my question, `curl` and `JSON` calls work but not the first one.

Comment: Can you post your BlogController def latest (or whatever action it goes to)?  Have you tried multiple browsers, like Mozilla, Chrome and/or IE?

Comment: Also, is this behind a proxy (Apache or Nginx)?  This paragraph from the how-to might apply to this issue: When using Devise + Rails together with HTTP Auth via Nginx or Apache

Comment: There isn't anything special about my controller code, it's the generic template with `json` added to it as such `format.json { render :json => @latest_articles }`. The thing is that it never hits the controller code, `Devise` hijacked it before it ever gets there. I put a debug statement as the first line in `blogs#latest` method and it never executed. I have tested it from Chrome, Safari and Firefox. On my dev machine, I'm using `thin` web server.